# Inserting a "duplicate" record into an Access database

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

**Problem:** I am using jackcess to create & insert record into table .I am trying to Insert duplicate Record into the table but i couldn't.

Is there is a way i can capture that there is an duplicate entry trying to be added if yes then concatenate an extra string to the PK and make it unique . when retrieving manipulate in query ?

i currently use the below code to insert into the DB .

```
 private static Database createDatabase(String databaseName) throws IOException {
        return Database.create(new File(databaseName));
    }

    private static TableBuilder createTable(String tableName) {
        return new TableBuilder(tableName);
    }

    public static void addColumn(Database database, TableBuilder tableName, String columnName, Types sqlType) throws SQLException, IOException {
        tableName.addColumn(new ColumnBuilder(columnName).setSQLType(Types.INTEGER).toColumn()).toTable(database);
    }

    public static void startDatabaseProcess() throws IOException, SQLException {
        String databaseName = "C:/Users/Alien/Documents/invited/employeedb.mdb"; // Creating an MS Access database
        Database database = createDatabase(databaseName);

        String tableName = "Employee"; // Creating table
        Table table;
        table = createTable(tableName)
          .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Id").setSQLType(Types.INTEGER).toColumn())
          .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Name").setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR).toColumn())
          .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Employer").setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR).toColumn())
          .toTable(database);

        table.addRow(453456, "ilakkiaselvan","google");//Inserting values into the table
    }
```

Comment: one way is to check for the id before insert, the other way is that the jdbc driver will throw an sqlexception with the specific error_id (like unique constraint violation or smt like this)

Comment: What is the underlying goal you are trying to accomplish? Generally databases maintain their integrity be disallowing duplicate data.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals i have a Few Entries in XML file created by some tool which might contain duplicates. my objective is to insert these into the DB and then generate a report or something , which specifies the duplicate entries so that the user can manually remove it from the tool so the future XML will not have duplicate entries

Comment: @anfy2002us i have a few hundred entries to be added you want me to compare all these before inserting will it not be expensive ? & i am not getting any unique constraint violation error or something when i run the above code ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is a way i can capture that there is an duplicate entry trying to be added if yes then concatenate an extra string to the PK and make it unique

If you set up your table with a Primary Key then Jackcess will throw an exception if you try to add a row where the primary key already exists. Your exception handler (`catch`) can tweak the primary key and keep trying until the insert succeeds.

In your case you have defined the PK as integer, so to "concatenate an extra string to the PK and make it unique" is a bit of a nuisance, but if you have a string PK then the code is very simple:

```java
import java.io.File;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;

public class jackcessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String newEmp_Id = "GT001";   // test data
        String newEmp_Name = "Gord";  //

        boolean insertedOK = false;
        int counter = 1;
        String insertEmp_Id = newEmp_Id;
        try {
            Table table = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("C:\\__tmp\\employeedb.mdb")).getTable("Employee");
            while (!insertedOK) {
                try {
                    table.addRow(insertEmp_Id, newEmp_Name);
                    insertedOK = true;
                    System.out.println(String.format("New record inserted as %s", insertEmp_Id));
                } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
                    insertEmp_Id = String.format("%s_copy%s", newEmp_Id, counter++);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When run on an empty table it adds the row normally:

```
Emp_Id       Emp_Name
-----------  --------
GT001        Gord
```

If you run it again it adds a second record with a modified key:

```
Emp_Id       Emp_Name
-----------  --------
GT001        Gord    
GT001_copy1  Gord
```

...and again...

```
Emp_Id       Emp_Name
-----------  --------
GT001        Gord    
GT001_copy1  Gord    
GT001_copy2  Gord
```

...and so on.

Comment: Note that the ConstraintViolationException is new as of the 2.0.2 release of jackcess.